# Warning: Unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I got this error

Warning: Unable to verify the first certificate

GET /api/GetShirts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 4d0ad166-7de9-41bd-a907-497b3dfe5540
Host: localhost:44303
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 01:47:25 GMT

Tried removing all the SSL certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this information: https://community.postman.com/t/unable-to-verify-first-cert-issue-enable-ssl-cert-verification-off/14951

"File > Settings > Request > SSL certificate verification = OFF"